# What tag fits, for questions about strategy but not for proofs?

Tags: support, tagging

I'm referring to questions from https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=trick
like:

- [Lesser-known integration tricks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks),
- [How do you prove that $n^n$ is $O(n!^2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46892/how-do-you-prove-that-nn-is-on2/46894#46894),
- [Ways to evaluate $\int \sec \theta \, \mathrm d \theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/ways-to-evaluate-int-sec-theta-d-theta),
- [slick way of transforming an integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265729/slick-way-of-transforming-an-integral)

If the question is about slick plans or tricks for a proof then [proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy) works. But what if the questions aren't about proofs? Like if they're only about calculations?  And they still need some crafty strategy or trick? What tag fits?

Comment: Frank, I'm not sure what sort of tricks you are talking about if you're not talking about tricks for proofs. In particular, all of the last three links you have cited were asking about tricks for a proof.

Comment: @EricStucky I updated. Aren't the links about calculations?

Comment: @FrankMuer Calculations are proofs.

Comment: I'd say the tags for integration tricks are "integration" and perhaps "definite-integration".